# Determine if function is called in a test using Perl

Tags: perl, function, testing

I use [`Test::More`](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore)

I want to see if one of my functions is called or not. There are two scenarios I have: one will not call my function, the other will. This function is not mocked out, I just want to see if it was called or not.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I'd like to see a code sample of exactly what you are calling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
my $called;
my $orig_function = \&YourPackage::YourFunction;
{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *YourPackage::YourFunction = sub { ++$called; goto &$orig_function };
}
# code that may or may not call YourFunction here
ok($called, 'function called');
```

Comment: can you describe a bit what this code does? I think I understand but am a bit confused on why you used the scoping after `my $orig_function...`

Comment: to limit the amount of code that had that warning turned off to just the one line

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're about to invent code coverage reports. Have you seen [Devel::Cover](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aCover)? It will make your life easier.